# How can I automatically update shortcut link when folder name changes

Tags: windows, shortcuts

I often update files inside a network folder.  I am required to provide a revision number as part of the folder name.  Hence, the name changes and the shortcuts on all the different computers are no longer valid as they are pointing to a non existent folder.

How can I automatically update the shortcut link to use the latest revision?

I've tried making a shortcut from a shortcut but it only copied the original shortcut.  I've thought about using wildcards in the original shortcut but don't know if that will work.

Thanks

Comment: Possible dup of [so] question [Editing shortcut (.lnk) properties with Powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/q/484560)

Comment: I can't remotely update the shortcut as the other question requires.  I need a way that will update the link when I set the shortcut on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided the easiest way to automatically update the shortcuts is to keep them pointing to a single file... a batch file.

When the batch file on the server runs it will point to the correct file inside the revision folder.  I can update the batch file to keep it in sync with my changes.